# Slide bar inside Modal

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal

please I try to create a slide bar component inside a b-modal, but it doesn't work. Any help please, I think I should reload the slide bar component after the modal shown, but I have no idea how to make.

Comment: How do you have 300 reputation but still ask such a broad question? :p

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is**

Add this property to b-modal

```
@shown="refreshSlide"
```

And then add this method

```
refreshSlide(){
    this.$refs.slidebar.refresh()
}
```